# Клик по заданным координатам

Tags: c#, selenium

Как осуществить клик по заданным координатам в Selenium ?

Подошли бы все варианты, как клик внутри элемента относительно его x=0;y=0 , так и вариант кликов без привязки к координатам элемента.

Пробовал:

```
new Actions(driver).MoveToElement(element).MoveByOffset(x,y).Click().Perform();
```

но что то не допру как это работает и получаю исключения...

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ixU48w5PeGo как вариант.

Comment: @Setplus c EN проблемы что бы искать, спасибо - попробую переварить.

Comment: @Setplus Блин, в видосе про локацию, а не клики, вопрос то был о другом, как клики то по координатам делать ?